# Laravel 5.7 getting images from storage

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-5.7

I have a little problem with getting an images from storage. Images are stored in **storage/app/public/uploads/files** directory. In database they are stored as file name image-1.png ... I am getting the files via url generated in Eloquent entity and url looks like **src="/uploads/files/image-1.png"** But cant see any image. Images are stored manually. Can somebody tell me please where is the problem?

Comment: did you create the symlink for `storage/app/public` to `public/storage` yet? (`php artisan storage:link`)

Comment: If you generate the symbolic link, then `/storage/uploads/files/image-1.png`

Comment: Yes I did.......

Comment: You are right. /storage/uploads/files/image-1.png is the right path. Make an acceptable answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate the symbolic link, then your path will be :

```
/storage/uploads/files/image-1.png
```